# lua help to get an end of string after last special character

Tags: string, design-patterns, lua, match

i have an unknow string,  that contains several "/". I need all characters after the last "/".
Example. (Remeber the actual string will be unknown)
string= abcdefg/hijkl/123hgj-sg/diejdu/duhd3/zyxw

I need return "zyxw"

thank you all for help

im just really bad with the symbols for pattern matching and no clue how to say "return everything after the last "/""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many ways leading to Rome?

```
> ustr = 'abcdefg/hijkl/123hgj-sg/diejdu/duhd3/zyxw'
> last = ustr:gsub('.*%/', '') -- I prefer gsub() method on string
> print(last)
zyxw
```

What to do if it is also unknown if Windows or Linux Path Convention?

```
> ustr = 'c:\\abcdefg\\hijkl\\123hgj-sg\\diejdu\\duhd3\\zyxw.ext'
> last = ustr:gsub('.*[%/%\\]', '') --[[ Checks for both: / and \ ]]
> print(last)
zyxw.ext
```

Answer (score 2):

```lua
local function getLastFromPath(path)
    local last = path:match("([^/]+)$")
    return last
end

print(getLastFromPath("abcdefg/hijkl/123hgj-sg/diejdu/duhd3/zyxw"))
```

Assuming you are referring to file-system paths, you can get the last bit of string by splitting every `/` and getting the last one in the path.

Comment: Note: You don't need the tmp var `last`, `match` will only return one value here.